# How can I show a single fact in output from the ansible.builtin.package_facts in an AWX playbook

Tags: ansible

I am trying to gather what versions of nginx are running on instances in Openstack.  I need to output if an instance has it or not, and if so, what version.  I am failing miserably.  Any help and patience would be greatly appreciated.

```
- name: Gather the package facts
  ansible.builtin.package_facts:
    manager: auto

- name: Check whether a package called nginx is installed
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: ansible_facts.packages['nginx']
    msg: "Nginx version is ={{ ansible_version | type_debug }}"
  when: "'nginx' in ansible_facts.packages"
  register: op
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are printing ansible_version? You need to print nginx version

```yaml
 name: Gather the package facts
  ansible.builtin.package_facts:
    manager: auto

- name: Check whether a package called nginx is installed
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "Nginx version is ={{ ansible_facts.packages['nginx']}}"
  when: "'nginx' in ansible_facts.packages"
  register: op
```

I deleted also the var, you are not using it.